# Understanding documentation for c++ concepts (weakly_incrementable)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to learn the concept of concepts in c++ and for this I wanted to create a type that is [std::weakly_incrementable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable).

The concept is as follow :

```
template< class I >

    concept weakly_incrementable =
        std::movable<I> &&
        requires(I i) {
            typename std::iter_difference_t<I>;
            requires /*is-signed-integer-like*/<std::iter_difference_t<I>>;
            { ++i } -> std::same_as<I&>; // not required to be equality-preserving
            i++;                         // not required to be equality-preserving
        };
```

I understand from this that my type has to

- have a preincrement that returns a reference to `I`
- have a postincrement operator

so look something like :

```
struct I {
    void operator*() {}
    I& operator++() { return *this; }
    void operator++(int){}
};
```

However it is not clear what the type requirement asks for exacactly

```
typename std::iter_difference_t<I>;
requires /*is-signed-integer-like*/<std::iter_difference_t<I>>;
```

In the end, looking at examples I found that I need the following

```
struct I {
    using difference_type = int; // needed because of type requirement
    void operator*() {}
    I& operator++() { return *this; }
    void operator++(int){}
};
```

but how do I guess or understand from the documentation that I need to define a type called `difference_type` and not `iter_difference_t` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::iter_difference_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) is an alias template defined in the standard library.

The requirement `typename std::iter_difference_t<I>;` is asking that `std::iter_difference_t<I>` is a valid type, and `requires /*is-signed-integer-like*/<std::iter_difference_t<I>>;` is asking that that type is signed-integer-like, which is described later on in the page.

`std::iter_difference_t<I>` is `std::iterator_traits<I>::difference_type` if you specialize [`std::iterator_traits<I>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), otherwise it is `std::incrementable_traits<I>::difference_type`.

[`std::incrementable_traits<I>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/incrementable_traits) by default has a `difference_type` member that is either `typename I::difference_type` if that exists or `std::make_signed_t<decltype(std::declval<I>() - std::declval<I>())>` if there is an `operator-`.

So there are 4 distinct ways to define `std::iter_difference_t`.

1. Specialize `std::iterator_traits<I>`:

   ```cpp
   struct I { I& operator++() { return *this; } void operator++(int) {} };
   template<>
   struct std::iterator_traits<I> {
       using difference_type = int;
   };
   static_assert(std::weakly_incrementable<I>);
   ```
2. Specialize `std::incrementable_triats<I>`:

   ```cpp
   struct I { I& operator++() { return *this; } void operator++(int) {} };
   template<>
   struct std::incrementable_traits<I> {
       using difference_type = int;
   };
   static_assert(std::weakly_incrementable<I>);
   ```
3. Provide a member `difference_type`, like you did
4. Provide an `operator-`:

   ```cpp
   struct I { I& operator++() { return *this; } void operator++(int) {} };
   int operator-(const I&, const I&);
   static_assert(std::weakly_incrementable<I>);
   ```